# Apache 2 mod_rewrite Inconsistent Results

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

My former university, SPSU, was "consolidated" into Kennesaw State University.  I used to have the domain `bbrown.spsu.edu`.  As a temporary fix, `bbrown.kennesaw.edu` was set up by University IT.  However, the permanent home for my web pages should be `http://ksuweb/faculty/rbrow211`.  I have administrative control of the server with the two "bbrown" domains.  I've put the following into `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bbrown.spsu.edu
ServerAlias www.bbrown.spsu.edu
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bbrown.kennesaw.edu
ServerAlias www.bbrown.kennesaw.edu
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

These two URLs behave as I expect, and redirect to the proper internal page on ksuweb:
http://bbrown.spsu.edu/misc/university_success.html
http://bbrown.kennesaw.edu/misc/university_success.html

**However** the first one of these works and the second does not!  It redirects to the index page at the top level, *i.e.* to http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/
http://bbrown.spsu.edu/it3203/2016_02/lab_7s.html
http://bbrown.kennesaw.edu/it3203/2016_02/lab_7s.html

*but* these two, with two levels of directory, work as expected:
http://bbrown.spsu.edu/it3123/2016_02/assign_0_classroom.html
http://bbrown.kennesaw.edu/it3123/2016_02/assign_0_classroom.html

I am utterly baffled.  My question?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Change ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211%{REQUEST_URI} to ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/$1 and see if that works better. Cheers!!

Comment: All these appear to redirect OK for me (ie. `http://bbrown.kennesaw.edu/it3203/2016_02/lab_7s.html` redirects to `http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/it3203/2016_02/lab_7s.html`). So, this would seem to be a local caching issue (if you've previously experimented with erroneous 301 redirects, then these will have been cached by the browser and possibly any intermediary caches)? The redirect code looks OK. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ could perhaps be simplified to `.*` or even `^` - but that won't make any difference in usage.

Comment: @w3dk: You are right!  Thank you! I guess that means this question should be closed, or should I delete it?  (Not sure if I *can* delete it.)

Comment: @BobBrown Rather than delete it, I've added that as an answer, with a bit extra. Caching is a common pitfall when dealing with 301 redirects, so may help to serve as a reminder for other readers.

Comment: @closetnoc Careful of those slashes. Since this directive is directly in the server config (not per-directory / .htaccess) then `$1` will already contain the slash prefix in this instance.

Comment: @w3dk Cheers!! I am soooooo out of practice I really should learn to stay away from these questions for a while. ;-) Of course I can be rather dense before coffee or late at night and some various points in between!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these appear to redirect OK for me (ie. `http://bbrown.kennesaw.edu/it3203/2016_02/lab_7s.html` redirects to `http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/it3203/2016_02/lab_7s.html`). So, this would seem to suggest a local caching issue. If you've previously experimented with erroneous 301 redirects, then these will have been cached by the browser and possibly any intermediary caches.

To avoid caching, either test with 302 (temporary) redirects. Or test with browser caching disabled. (In Google Chrome, you can open the Object Inspector and on the "Network" tab, check the "Disable cache" option.)

The redirect code looks OK. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* could perhaps be simplified to `.*` or even `^` (since you aren't using the captured group in the substitution) - but that won't make any difference in usage.